# Does 401k on H-1b visa make sense when there is an employer match?

Tags: united-states, 401k, employer-match, h-1b-visa

I am on H-1b visa in the U.S. I will stay between 2 and 5 years here. My employer is (almost) matching my 401k contribution.

I am wondering if it makes sense for me to participate in the 401k. I have no intention of using it at retirement age, due to my situation. I have done the rough calculation and I think it does, but I might be missing something.

So I contribute $191.67 twice a month. The employer contributes $143.80 twice a month. I become vested after 2 years of employment.

```
2 years, no 401k:
24 * 191.67 * 2 = 9200 - 2024 = $7,176 after tax (I've put roughly 22% for tax)

2 years, with 401k:
24 * 191.67 * 2 = $9200 own contributions
24 * 143.80 * 2 = $6902 employer
9200 + 6902 = 16102 - 5313 = $10,789 after tax and penalty (22% tax, 10% penalty)
```

So at minimum, I am ahead with $3,613 as soon as I become vested, even with the 10% penalty. I am aware that if I leave the employer even a month before the 2 years vesting period, I'd lose money. e.g.:

```
2 years, 401k, quit a month before vesting:
23 * 191.67 * 2 = 8816.82 own
8816 - 2909 = $5,907 after tax and penalty. i.e. lose $1,269
```

But if I work for 5 years, I'd be ahead with $9,032 thanks to the employer's contribution.

I am not even counting the market fluctuation for my investments. Let's just assume I don't lose money on the market.

Any holes in my 'airtight' financial plan? Can I 'abuse' the 401k as a short-term investment strategy?

**Two year update**: my bet worked out. I am ahead with $8,500 in employer matching. Even if I withdraw now, that would be -$2,000 in total 10% penalties, or I would be still ahead with $6,500.

Comment: Why would you have no intention of using it at retirement age?  AFAIK (though I'm no expert), you could simply let the money sit in that account (or a rollover IRA) and grow for several decades.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your calculations look right and I think your strategy is sound. The 10% penalty is enough to persuade most people from withdrawing from their 401(k) early but not enough to be really punitive in case of special situations like yours. Plus you have a very generous employer match which shifts the balance toward contributing. The only things I'd recommend checking with your calculations are (1) is the 401(k) contribution entirely within the 22% bracket? and (2) is it possible your 401(k) balance would be large enough that some of the withdrawal would get bumped into the 24% or 32% bracket? That would obviously make it less advantageous.

Another possibility to consider. You might be able to contribute to a Roth 401(k). You don't get the tax benefit up-front, but after you rollover to a Roth IRA you can withdraw your contributions immediately (earnings would have to wait) with no tax or penalty. Your employer matching would be the same amount and still go into a pre-tax account, so you'd still pay income tax and 10% early withdrawal penalty on that portion. But it'd allow you to avoid the penalty on about half of your money. Since your tax rate now is probably the same or lower than when you withdraw, making your contributions Roth would make sense here.

Comment: Re: tax bracket at the time of withdrawal - OP will likely reside outside of the US by then, so he will be a non-resident alien, so only his US income will be taxed, albeit under NRA taxation rules.

Comment: I'd withdraw before I leave. So with Roth my own contributions are not penalized for early withdrawal?

Comment: I just looked it up though and it's true only under particular conditions (including the account being 5+ years old)

Comment: @Ицко Sorry, I clarified that only your Roth 401(k) contributions can be withdrawn immediately without tax or penalty after a rollover. Your earnings would indeed have to wait or you'd owe tax + penalty.

Comment: @Ицко Note that you could substantially lower your tax liability by spreading the withdrawals over few years following your departure. On your last year, if you have your employment income, and you withdraw 5 years worth of 401(k) contributions all at once, your tax bill will be brutal. Roth 401(k) avoids the final year tax bill increase, but does nothing to lower your taxes during your H1B years, unlike traditional 401(k) which does that.

Comment: @void_ptr It depends on if withdrawing the entire pre-tax 401(k) balance would push OP into a higher tax bracket. If not, the tax rate will be the same whether they withdraw all at once or spread over multiple years.

Comment: @CraigW Except that OP will be NRA with no US income soon after his departure, which guarantees lower tax bracket if withdrawals are spread over multiple years after OP's H1B ends.

Comment: @void_ptr True but sounds like they want to withdraw it all at once anyway. If possible, it would be great if they leave their job at the end of a year, and space the withdrawals over two calendar years.

Comment: @CraigW Ицко is on his first H1B year, since he has 2 or 5 years left. He may not yet realize just how much money he can save by doing this in a smart way, which is _not_ to withdraw all at once, let alone in the same year when he is still employed in the US.

Comment: When I withdraw money from the 401k in a given year it would count towards the income for the year and could put me in a higher bracket, I get that. But what if I withdraw the 401k in the first year I don't have another US income? It can't possibly be above even the lowest bracket?

Comment: @Ицко You could definitely end up above the lowest bracket. But even without the standard deduction, roughly $10k will get taxed at 10%, then another roughly $30k at 12%, before you get back to the 22% bracket.